# Collect stream of set of Characters

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this Stream of set of Characters:

`Stream<Set<Character>> characterSet`

Now I want to convert this Stream into a simple Set of Characters and I do:

`Set<Character> newSet = characterSet.collect(Collectors.toSet());`

However, I get this error:

`Incompatible types. Required Set<Character> but 'collect' was inferred to R: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Set<Character> conforms to Character inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Character lower bounds: Set<Character>.`

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: `Set<Character> newSet = characterSet.flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet())`.

Answer (score 1):

Given below is an example of how to do it:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Character> newSet = Stream.of(Set.of('A', 'B'), Set.of('C', 'D'))
                                    .flatMap(s -> s.stream())
                                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        System.out.println(newSet);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[A, B, C, D]
```

So, in your case, it will be as shown below:

```
Set<Character> newSet = characterSet.flatMap(s -> s.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```